# How to capture code metrics in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-metrics

I want to write my code more cleaner. For this purpose  I'm looking for a tool to generate code metrics in Xcode. I'd like to have a statistic showing me how many tests, classes etc. were added. And the main goal is retrieving cyclomatic complexity of a program.

Does anyone know a good Xcode tools or plugin that could provide me some code metrics?

Comment: What did you end up using here?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Xcode Statistician](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/freestuff/XcodeStatistician.zip).

Comment: Nice! Any idea what they mean by "Main File" as used in the "Count code in main files only"?

Comment: I think it means to count in implementation files (.m extension) only, while skipping header files (.h extension).

Comment: Thank you, but what about retrieving cyclomatic complexity of application?

Comment: If you use it, you should group your classes inside folders in the `Project Navigator` inside `xCode`. If you use folders inside your project `Xcode Statistician` won't be able to give you stats of all files.

Answer (score 1):

A paying (~$5) but good solution: [Project Statistics for Xcode](http://www.lamobratory.com/project-statistics-xcode/).

Comment: @Volker - The answer actually answers the question. The problem is in the question.

Comment: @jww You're right, I should have looked more into detail to the question.